# Navigation left button back to Master view does not show on IPAD

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios10

I have splitview controller with several detail views embedded in navigation view controller. On Ipad, most of the detail views show left button that displays the master view. However, there are two detail views that does not show left button. As a result, I cannot go back to master view unless I rotate the device. This is what my views look like in interface builder.

[image]
[image]

Categories view is the master view and the rest are detail views. The segue modes are all "Show Detail" for detail views.

As you can see, there is no left bar button to bring back Category master view.

[image]

But for Filter view, it's there. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why is there a second navigation controller? There is one before the "Note Gallery" view and one after. There should be one before, and the navigation controller handles all pages added onto the hierarchy

Comment: I'm new to this and wasn't really sure what I was doing. But I removed it but the problem still persist.